dependency injection pattern properly usage
I use the dependency injection pattern. I have a container with dependencies. And there is a consumer class that starts reading from the queue after calling the consume method and it is not anyone's dependency. Do I need to put it in a container?
It seems to me that no, since again it is not anyone's dependency, but is some endpoint like a rest api endpoint

Your question is too broad to be a good fit for Stack Overflow. Please be specific and add concrete code examples. Also add the proper tags to indicate the languages and frameworks you are using. Without more detailed information, I'm afraid your question will be closed quickly.
